NestJS FCM - Error fetching access token: Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET
I have set up a nestJS project to send messages using Firebace(FCM)
app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FirebaseModule } from './firebase.module';
import { NotificationController } from './notification.controller';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [FirebaseModule],
  controllers: [NotificationController, AppController],
  providers: [NotificationService, AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}


app.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }

  @Get('readiness')
  getReadiness(): string {
    return this.appService.getReadiness();
  }

  @Get('liveness')
  getLiveness(): string {
    return this.appService.getLiveness();
  }
}


app.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }

  getLiveness(): string {
    return 'Alive';
  }

  getReadiness(): string {
    return 'Ready';
  }
}


firebase.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';

import * as serviceAccount from './google-services.json';

// import { applicationDefault } from 'firebase-admin/app';

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'FIREBASE_INSTANCE',
      useValue: admin,
    },
    FirebaseService,
  ],
  exports: [FirebaseService],
})
export class FirebaseModule {}



firebase.service.ts
import { Injectable, Inject, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(FirebaseService.name);

  constructor(
    @Inject('FIREBASE_INSTANCE') private readonly firebase: admin.app.App,
  ) {}

  async sendPushNotification(deviceToken: string, payload: any) {
    try {
      const message = {
        data: payload,
        token: deviceToken,
      };
      const response = await this.firebase.messaging().send(message);
      console.log('Notification sent successfully: ', response);
      this.logger.log('Notification sent successfully: ', response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending notification: ', error);
      this.logger.error('Error sending notification: ', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}



notification.controller.ts
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
  Post,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Controller('notifications')
export class NotificationController {
  constructor(private readonly notificationService: NotificationService) {}

  @Post('send')
  async sendPushNotification(
    @Body() body: { deviceToken: string; payload: any },
  ) {
    const { deviceToken, payload } = body;

    try {
      await this.notificationService.sendPushNotification(deviceToken, payload);
      return { message: 'Push notification sent' };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
      throw new HttpException(
        'Failed to end push notification',
        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      );
    }
  }
}



notification.service.ts
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(NotificationService.name);

  constructor(private readonly firebaseService: FirebaseService) {}

  async sendPushNotification(deviceToken: string, payload: any) {
    try {
      await this.firebaseService.sendPushNotification(deviceToken, payload);
      this.logger.log('Push notification sent successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error sending push notification:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}



I tried a POST request to the service for sending the notification and I got the error:
Error sending notification:  FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET".
    at C:\Users\achuan\WORK\firebase-poc\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\app\firebase-app.js:86:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at FirebaseService.sendPushNotification (C:\Users\achuan\WORK\firebase-poc\src\firebase.service.ts:18:24)
    at NotificationService.sendPushNotification (C:\Users\achuan\WORK\firebase-poc\src\notification.service.ts:12:7)
    at NotificationController.sendPushNotification (C:\Users\achuan\WORK\firebase-poc\src\notification.controller.ts:21:7)
    at C:\Users\achuan\WORK\firebase-poc\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28    at C:\Users\achuan\WORK\firebase-poc\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17 {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/invalid-credential',
    message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET".'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app'
}

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix this?
